# I can tunnel using terminal but not using mobaxterm gui, why?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

```
ssh -L machine_port:forwarded_ip:forwarded_port user@ip_of_ssh_server -p port_of_ssh_server
```

Example.

- SSH server is `10.50.10.50`.
- SSH port is 22.
- **Remote server is of same ip i.e `localhost`. I've tried both `localhost` and `10.50.10.50` and the ip that I get by `ip a` command in Terminal.**
- Remote port is 4080.
- forwarded port is 1278.

When I put those values in the gui below it doesn't work. But when I type this command it works and I am able to access the remote port on chrome browser. Why is this happening? And how to fix this?

The command in use is this:

```
ssh -L 4080:localhost:1278 user@10.50.10.50 -p 22
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] and post the command and the screenshot with all the values filled in. My concern is `forwarded_port` in the command and `<Forwarded port>` in the screenshot are very similar names but logically `forwarded_port` is `<Remote port>`; we really don't know what you put where, so *maybe* the problem is you mixed something up. Or at least in the command use "variables" clearly corresponding to the fields in the screenshot.

Comment: I'vee edited the post. Please check.

Comment: I cannot see any of the input fields being populated as recommendet by @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: The question is still a mess when it comes to descriptive names. You wrote "remote port is 4080" and there is indeed `<Remote port>` in the screenshot, but in the current command "template" you have `machine_port`, `forwarded_port` and `port_of_ssh_server`. Well, in your actual command there is `-L 4080:localhost:1278`. Here `4080` is the `<Forwarded port>`, `1278` is the `<Remote port>`. This does not correspond to your claim that "remote port is 4080". *Maybe* this is the culprit, maybe it's just a clumsiness of the question; anyway we (including you in the first place) should sort this out.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski updated the question. I'm sorry for inconvenience. I didn't have my laptop with me last night.

Answer (score 1):

The fields in your first screenshot

> [image: original screenshot with empty fields]

translate to `ssh` like this:

```
ssh -p <SSH port> -L <Forwarded port>:<Remote server>:<Remote port> <SSH login>@<SSH server>
```

If `-L 4080:localhost:1278` works (and you claim it does), then `4080` is the `<Forwarded port>` and `1278` is the `<Remote port>`, not the other way around.

Locally (i.e. on "My computer with MobaXterm") you connect to `localhost:4080`; then the SSH server connects to (its) `localhost:1278` on your behalf.